# IE Browser window jumps to the top of the form (not page) after the AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

PHP/JQuery/AJAX problem's here:

I have a button at the bottom of the page that calls a JQuery function through AJAX call, and then, based on some variable from a database (that's why the AJAX is here) it enables the answer textbox, also located at the bottom of the page. The problem is that the browser scrolls/jumps to the top of the form, not the page (there's some images above the form).

I think I might know the possible root cause - I'm adding new Date().getTime() to the php file url so IE would't cache the result, but it also tells the browser that the link is new and it should go to the top of the page. But it goes to the top of the form, so I'm guessing it's something manageable.

**It's happening in IE only. Chrome, FF = OK.**

Any thoughts?

The form tag:

```
<form method="get" id="advisors_form" name="advisors_form">
```

The ajax call structure:

```
    $.ajax( {
        type : 'GET',
        url : 'Code/f_aa_answer_request_check.php?' + new Date().getTime(),
        data : request_data,
        success : function(response) {
            if (response == 'success') {
                alert("OK");
            }
    }});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved my own problem!

added return false after the ajax call:

```
$.ajax( {
        type : 'GET',
        url : 'Code/f_aa_answer_request_check.php?' + new Date().getTime(),
        data : request_data,
        success : function(response) {
            if (response == 'success') {
                alert("OK");
            }
    }});
return false;
```